# 0-dimensional quasi projective variety

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, projective-geometry, projective-space

Let $Z$ be a closed set in a quasi projective variety $X$.

**My question is**
what can we say about $Z$ if $\dim Z=0?$

I know $\dim Z=0$ implies all irreducible components of $Z$ is zero-dimensional.